How can we say in Latin "I don't want to be forgotten."?
I've always found the deponent verbs really interesting in Latin. It's a passive voice, but the meaning is active. So far so good...
I was writing a song in Latin and a line made me realise that I wouldn't be able to say "I don't want to be forgotten" since "oblivisci" means "to forget" not "to be forgotten". How can we translate such meanings with the verb in the infinitive form?(If it's possible, of course) I don't wanna change the phrase into Accusative with infinitive "nolo te oblivisci mei/me.
[I found this in L&S "2. ulciscor, ci, in a passive signif.:
“quicquid sine sanguine civium ulcisci nequitur, jure factum sit,” Sall. J. 31, 8: ob iras graviter ultas, graviter ultae, Liv 2, 17, 7; so,
“ultus,” avenged, Val. Fl. 4, 753
“ulta ossa patris,” Ov. H. 8, 120."] Can we use the verb "oblivisci" thus, as well?

Related post: this

I believe the Latin for "I don't want to be forgotten" is Myosotis sylvatica ;-)

The problem of expressing the passive, "forgotten", in Latin, has occurred before. In Q: Gone But Not Forgotten, TKR dealt with this by saying, "fall out of memory", giving:

"memoria excidere non cupio." =


"I don't want to fall out of memory." i.e. "I don't want to be forgotten."

